# Insert NULL value into INT column

Tags: mysql

How can I insert NULL value into INT column with MySQL?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If the column has the `NOT NULL` constraint then it won't be possible; but otherwise this is fine:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(MyIntColumn) VALUES(NULL);
```

Answer (score 16):

2 ways to do it

> insert tbl (other, col1, intcol) values ('abc', 123, **NULL**)

or just omit it from the column list

> insert tbl (other, col1) values ('abc', 123)

Answer (score 4):

Does the column allow null?

Seems to work. Just tested with phpMyAdmin, the column is of type int that allows nulls:

```
INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`column`) VALUES (NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

If column is not `NOT NULL` (nullable).

You just put `NULL` instead of value in `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the insert query and put the NULL keyword without quotes. That will work-

```
INSERT INTO `myDatabase`.`myTable` (`myColumn`) VALUES (NULL);
```

Answer (score -3):

The optimal solution for this is provide it as '0' and while using string use it as 'null' when using integer.

ex:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column_name) VALUES(NULL);
```

Comment: 0 and null has very different meanings. Null could mean we do not have the data. 0 means we know it is zero.

Or lets imagine a referecence to user_id. 0 will point to record with id 0 while null means there is no user.