# Mysql int will not store non zero based null.

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to figure out how to get mysql to store an int value as 'null', instead it continues to give it a zero based value. In my case zero has a meaning to the app. Anybody know how I can store actual nulls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert NULL value into INT column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338529/insert-null-value-into-int-column)

Comment: Or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449708/how-to-insert-null-in-mysql-especially-int-datatype)

Comment: No that is very different. I can insert a null value, however it converts it to zero. I can't have it converting to zero and my column is setup to accept nulls.

Comment: Define converts it to 0? In the database?

Comment: When I run this sql statement UPDATE my_table
SET field1=null
WHERE field1 = 0; The values remain zero. I can not get the database to show null, it only shows zero and they mean two completely different things.

Comment: default is NULL ALTER TABLE `my_database`.`my_table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `field1` `field1` INT(7) DEFAULT NULL ;

Comment: Have you tried inserting into the table without inserting into that column?

Comment: Yeah, my varchar columns show null. Is there is a sql configuration setting that is causing this?.

Comment: If you insert into the varchar and not the int column does it put a null in there?? Like dont insert anything into that column... Honestly ive only seen 0 get converted to null not the other way around.. Cant do much to test it as is

Comment: I just tried inserting a new record leaving field1 as a null and it displays it as a zero. I did this directly from workbench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on my mobile phone so I can't test this...  Also this is too long to be a comment... first thing try selecting the rows in question.. Then if they arent returned try updating a select when the rows are equal to 0.

Maybe it is null but you have a setting in mysql workbench that shows a 0 instead

```
SELECT id, field1 
FROM table 
WHERE field1 IS NULL;
```

If that doesn't return the rows then do this

```
SELECT id, field1
FROM table
WHERE field1 =0
```

If that does then try an update with these exact rows

```
UPDATE table t,
(   SELECT id, field1
    FROM table
    WHERE field1 = 0
) temp
SET t.field1 = NULL
WHERE t.id = temp.id
```

Hope that is helpful

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what I did, but for some reason, it is finally working now. Thank You John.

Comment: Sure thing... Interesting issue you had

Answer (score 1):

You just write `null`:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t (i INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t VALUES (null);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM t;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM t WHERE i IS NULL;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: believe me I did, I have no idea what was causing this issue.

Comment: I did up above under my question

Comment: But it's working now, it could have been a workbench glitch for all I know.